# Make one SPAN fit another SPAN height

Tags: css

I'm desperatly trying to make two aligned span to match each other in height in mobile view.

This is the code :
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oMgYEe

```css
    .td_btn {
        cursor: pointer;
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        font-weight: 600;
    }

    .td_btn_md {
        padding: 9px 12px;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 20px;
    }

    .td_outlined_btn {
        border-width: 2px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-radius: 4px;
        background-color: transparent;
        transition: all 0.1s ease;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease;
    }
```

```html
HTML :
<div class="btn-sidebar">
       <span style="margin-right: 5px;">
       <a href="#">
       <span class="td_btn td_btn_md td_outlined_btn">Button</span>
       </a>
       </span>
       <a href="#">
       <span class="td_btn td_btn_md td_outlined_btn">Button Partner</span>
       </a>
    </div>
```

While they look good here when parent div is more than 228px, when parent div is resized to 228px wide, the right button get bigger than the other one because it has more text, and it then takes 2 lines of text. SEE:

[image]

I can't use white-space no wrap because then the text goes past the size of the button, and I don't want to resize the font size to make it fit one line of text.

What I want instead is to make the first button to match the second button heigh

Any idea ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Flexbox can do that.

```css
.td_btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-flex;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  height: 100%;
}

.td_btn_md {
  padding: 9px 12px;
  font-size: 16px;
  align-content: center;
  margin-right: 5px;
  ;
}

.td_outlined_btn {
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: all 0.1s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease;
}

.btn-sidebar {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.skinny {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-sidebar">
  <a href="#"><span class="td_btn td_btn_md td_outlined_btn">Button</span></a>
  <a href="#"><span class="td_btn td_btn_md td_outlined_btn">Button Partner</span></a>
</div>

<div class="btn-sidebar skinny">
  <a href="#"><span class="td_btn td_btn_md td_outlined_btn">Button</span></a>
  <a href="#"><span class="td_btn td_btn_md td_outlined_btn">Button Partner</span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow thanks Paulie, that's pure magic, I'm going to study your code to undestand this tweak ! Currently quite struggling to learn (beginner), that was very helpful !